# Which actions will cancel One For All? Which won't?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

The Mec skill One For All allows a MEC Trooper to act as high cover for their meatsack comrades for the duration of the turn, provided the MEC Trooper doesn't use an arm-based weapon. This is deliciously vague, as is tradition for XCOM:EU skill descriptions. What exactly can and a MEC Trooper do without canceling One For All?

Answer (score 3):

The arm based weapons are, quite literally, the two weapons attached to the arms.

For the initial MEC-Warden, this means the Minigun, Kinetic Strike Fist, and Flamethrower will all disable One For All.

Reloading and overwatch do not end the effect.

Comment: Does shooting from overwatch cancel it? What about reactive fire from the colonel skill?

Comment: @kotekzot Sure does. Not sure about the colonel ability, don't have a colonel MEC yet. (But I'd presume that it does as well)

Comment: I see. What about 2nd and 3rd tier chasis upgrades?

Comment: @kotekzot 2nd tier upgradse (grenade launcher / mists) don't deactivate it.